# Problem using scanner on my multifunction Samsung SL-M2070 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scanner

Printer works OK, but ubuntu can not find scanner, i have installed driver but ubuntu still can not find the scanner.

In 12.04 the problem did not occur!

What do i do wrong?

And i wonder is there any scanner on the market that works on ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Could you make the scanner work? I am contemplating to buy this printer/scanner, too.

Comment: Same problem in 14.04 with newest available driver v1.00.37_00.99!

Answer (score -2):

First check if the cable is working correctly!

If so, then check if any drivers available through samsung's website or Software center and install them.

Comment: -1: Why should he check the cable, if printing is working. Further a driver has been installed